# What is the longest palindrome word in English?

Tags: orthography, palindrome

I want to know what the longest palindrome word is.

Comment: The two shortest palindrome words, excluding one-letter words and abbreviations, are: **aa** (a basaltic lava) and **oo** (aka *‘Ō‘ō*, aka *o-o*; an extinct Hawaiian bird)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[Detartrated](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/detartrated).

**Edit:** surprise, surprise, Wikipedia [has more](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palindrome#Long_palindromes):

> The longest palindromic word in the Oxford English Dictionary is the [onomatopoeic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Onomatopoeia) *tattarrattat*, coined by [James Joyce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James_Joyce) in [*Ulysses*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ulysses_%28novel%29) (1922) for a knock on the door. The Guinness Book of Records gives the title to *detartrated*, the [preterit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preterite) and past participle of *detartrate*, a chemical term meaning to remove [tartrates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tartrate). [*Rotavator*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotary_tiller), a trademarked name for an agricultural machine, is often listed in dictionaries. The term *redivider* is used by some writers but appears to be an invented or derived term—only *redivide* and *redivision* appear in the Shorter Oxford Dictionary. [*Malayalam*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malayalam), an Indian language, is of equal length.

So let's see:

```
tattarrattat  (onomatopoeic)
detartrated
Rotavator     (trademark)
redivider     (disputed)
Malayalam
```

Comment: thank you RegDwight. can you tell me the meaning of the of the word

Comment: @khan: it's a link. Click on it. \\(^_^)/

Comment: I suspect that tattarrattat was invented to be palindromic, so I don't think it should count!

Comment: Also: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nej4xJe4Tdg

Comment: There is also *aibohphobia*, the fear of palindromes. :-)

Comment: Tsilihphilist, I believe, is another fun (but manufactured) word to describe someone who likes palindromes!

Answer (score 2):

Not that long, but indisputable: racecar

(Though my browser does not care for the spelling. Did my 6th grade English teacher mislead me?)

Answer (score 2):

How about an eatery in northern California called the Yrekabakery?

Comment: ["Yreka Bakery"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yreka,_California#Trivia) is two words.