# What is the longest palindromic phrase?

Tags: phrases, palindrome

Somewhat related to [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/13844/what-is-the-longest-palindrome-word-in-english), but I'm interested in a *phrase*, not just a single word.

The longest I am aware of is

> A man, a plan, a canal: Panama

Are there longer palindromic phrases?

Comment: Seems "off topic" to me.

Comment: if only there were a palindrome that means "off topic"

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is no upper limit to how long a palindrome can be.  [Poems have been written that are palindromes](http://www.pastemagazine.com/articles/2009/02/demetri-martins-palindrome-poem.html).

Comment: It makes sense that there is no upper limit in theory - I am curious which have been discovered and are meaningful.

Comment: Well, but Demetri Martin is just stringing individual palindromes together. Hardly a coherent statement.

Comment: Only the first two and last two lines are individual palindromes.

Comment: Ah, true. I didn't notice that at first.

Answer (score 12):

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palindrome#Long_palindromes):

> In English, **two palindromic novels have been published**: *Dr Awkward & Olson in Oslo* by Lawrence Levine (1986, 31954 words), and *Satire: Veritas* by David Stephens (1980, **58795 words**). In French, Oulipo writer George Perec's "Grand Palindrome" (1969) is 5,556 letters in length. In Hebrew, Ghil'ad Zuckermann wrote a 153-word palindromic story called "Lear's in Israel."

For *much* shorter palindromes: The first place I look for constrained writing is [Mike Keith's website](http://www.cadaeic.net/), and it has a [few short palindromes](http://www.cadaeic.net/palind.htm) and a [story about them](http://www.cadaeic.net/silopolis.htm), though neither is as impressive as some of his other work.

Comment: Oh, and there's a genre of Sanskrit poetry called *viloma-kavya*, in which reading the verses forwards narrates one story, and reading them backwards narrates a different story.

Answer (score 4):

The longest coherent palindromic <strike>statement</strike> *sentence* I've ever heard of was reported by Brendan Gill of *The New Yorker*, which I encountered in a book of his some years ago.

> T. Eliot, top bard, notes putrid tang emanating, is sad; I'd assign it a name: gnat dirt upset on drab pot toilet.

Answer (score 4):

Peter Norvig discusses this [here](http://norvig.com/palindrome.html), suggests his own, and links to another possibility.

Comment: Thank you! Great answer, and website. Peter Norvig is more versatile than I ever realized.

Answer (score 2):

This is a longer palindromic phrase (though not necessarily the longest possible):

> Doc, note I dissent. A fast never prevents a fatness. I diet on cod.